# How can I build a .NET Framework 4.8 application using the dotnet CLI?

Tags: c#, .net

I have inherited a .NET Framework 4.8 application that I'm able to compile using Visual Studio, however when trying to compile it using the `dotnet` CLI Application I get CS0246 errors for all types I use from external dependencies.
The original error message, sorry for the German:

```
Archiver\Archiver.cs(2,7): error CS0246: Der Typ- oder Namespacename "log4net" wurde nicht gefunden (möglicherweise fehlt eine using-Direktive oder ein Assemblyverweis).
```

When running `dotnet --list-sdk` I get the following output:

```
3.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I've tried reinstalling and repairing the .NET Framework 4.8 multiple times but that didn't fix anything.

What do I need to do make the CLI realize where the framework is and hopefully fix my error?

Comment: Can you post your .csproj?

Comment: Why do you want to use the tools for one platform (.NET Core) to build a project from another (.NET Framework)? (Seems like an X-Y problem.)

Comment: @Richard: I want to build the project with a CLI to have builds and tests running on CI. I assumed dotnet would be the appropriate CLI tool for building .NET projects. Sorry for the wrong assumption

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<strike>You can't.</strike> It's complicated, see below.

`dotnet` is the CLI for .NET Core/.NET 5 and higher. <strike>It has never been compatible with .NET Framework .csproj projects and never will be.</strike> (It's complicated, see below.)

The answer you're looking for is basically: To build your .NET Framework project/solution from the command line, use MSBuild (or if you really, really, really have to use Visual Studio, `devenv`).

You may be able to build a new, "SDK-style" project that [targets net48 or similar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks). These projects were introduced with .NET Core and most .NET Framework projects in the wild are not of this type. To my knowledge, no template in Visual Studio produces them for .NET Framework projects since they haven't been built for it. For example, when using the Entity Framework NuGet package in one, the tooling is not installed and integrated the way it usually would be, since NuGet is integrated entirely differently between .NET Framework csprojs and "SDK-style" csprojs. If you have a project of this type, chances are you either a) created a .NET Standard project, b) created a .NET Core project and made it also target `net48`, or c) created an SDK-style csproj more or less by hand.

In any case, there is no SDK for `dotnet` to target .NET Framework, and it does not know what to do with .NET Framework-based Web Sites, ASP.NET csprojs, WPF/Windows Forms csprojs, Class Library csprojs and so on.

Comment: Okay, so since I have a legacy application, I have to figure out how to install MSBuild and then the project should just build because that's what Visual Studio does as well?

Comment: [Download "build tools"](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools) and you get MSBuild. Some components are only buildable by running Visual Studio, but try MSBuild first, it gives you a lot more control and also requires fewer resources since it is just the build engine.

Comment: Worth noting -- you can usually update your .NET Framework 4.8 project files that compile to 'library' (dll) outputs to the latest NET/Core style project format. This has some benefits in Visual Studio such as being able to edit the project file without unloading, add files to the project folders and see them immediately, and little things like that. You can even then get tests for the libraries to run via `dotnet test`. However, it doesn't seem like you can build the top-level EXE project via `dotnet build`.

Comment: I have just successfully run MSBuild from Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools (but without installing Visual Studio) on a ancient soltuion that started from .NET Framework 2.0 and in years gradually upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8.1. The project thoroughly uses WinForms. Compiled .exe runs as it should. Now, I have to reproduce the same in a Docker image.