# testing .net4.8 in VScode using dotnet CLI

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mstest, dotnet-cli

I am trying to transform an old non-SDK-style mstest project that was generated with Visual Studio into a new SDK-style project using only Visual Studio Code.

I read and followed [this little how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/testing-library-with-visual-studio-code), but this is only for .NET core and newer; not for .NET framework.

I need my project to target both. If I do it like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;netcoreapp3.1;net5.0;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net48'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.UnitTesting" Version="11.0.50727.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net48'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and add some test like this

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace MyTests {

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestTwoPlusTwoIsFour()
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(2 + 2 == 4);
        }
    }

}
```

and run `dotnet test` on my `csproj`, then only `netcoreapp3.1`, `net5.0`, `net6.0` get tested. The `net48` does not occur anywhere in my console output.

**What do I need to do in order to test all four frameworks?**

Comment: It looks like you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795173/87698

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69795173/5333340) use `dotnet test` for it but need `msbuild`. (Thanks for the comment, @Heinzi.)

I can run it like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:"$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(OutputPath)$(ProjectName).dll"
```

It would be nice if this can somehow be [incorporated into my `dotnet test` call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71081351/5333340), so I don't need two calls...