# How do I get Azure DevOps to build a .NET 4.8 app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure-devops

When we run dotnet build on a .net 4.8 app, we get an error message. I attempted to install the developer pack for 4.8. However, that fails and I think the reason it fails is that .NET 4.8 is already installed on the system. What's the right way to resolve this issue?

> ##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1221,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

Is it that we cannot use dotnet build for 4.8 apps? Do we need to use MSBuild instead?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a private agent or a Microsoft-hosted agent? What does your pipeline YAML look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I build a .NET Framework 4.8 application using the dotnet CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795081/how-can-i-build-a-net-framework-4-8-application-using-the-dotnet-cli)

Comment: You call it a ".net 4.8 app", but your error message says "assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found". This suggests to me that your project file is targeting .NET 4.0, so why are you calling it a ".net 4.8 app"?

Comment: because in the web.config file we are targetting 4.8. We can target 4.7.1, 4.7.2, or 4.8. We don't really care which of those we use. I confirmed that 4.8 is installed on the Azure DevOps server.

Answer (score 1):

It requires the build agent be windows based, e.g. `vmImage: 'windows-2022'`.

```yaml
 - task: VSBuild@1
   displayName: 'Dotnet build'
   inputs:
     solution: '*.sln'
     msbuildArgs: '/t:build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutputPath="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
     restoreNugetPackages: true
     configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The above assumes the solution file is located in the root of the source repository.

While `restoreNugetPackages` is optional I received package not found errors until enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is tagged as `[asp.net]`, the question is generic to possibly catch those who are getting this for other types of projects.

For those who want to build SDK-Style projects targeting .NET 4.8 in Azure DevOps on Linux machines (e.g. building multi-targeted libraries to use latest APIs from .NET 5+ while also supporting .NET 4.8) and are receiving this error:

> Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

You need to install Mono:

```yaml
  - script: |
      sudo apt install -y ca-certificates gnupg
      sudo gpg --homedir /tmp --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/mono-official-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
      echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mono-official-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
      sudo apt update
      sudo apt install -y mono-devel
    displayName: Install Mono
```

The DotNetCli tasks should work after that (if your library is compatible with Mono's .NET 4.8 implementation).