How to create a new C# Console App (.NET Framework) project from command line in Visual Studio 2019?
I'm trying to automate the creation of a new C# Console Application (.NET Framework) project using the command line in Visual Studio Professional 2019. I prefer using devenv.com or devenv.exe, but I'm open to other methods using cmd batch or PowerShell.
I've tried the following command, but it doesn't work:
devenv.com /new "Console App (.NET Framework)" /name:MyProject

This results in an error message:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.40.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Invalid Command Line. Unknown Switch : new.

Is there a way to create a new project from the command line in Visual Studio 2019? I'm specifically looking for methods that don't use dotnet.exe from .NET Core, as I need to stick with the .NET Framework.

This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795081/how-can-i-build-a-net-framework-4-8-application-using-the-dotnet-cli

I need to stick with the .NET Framework. why? There may be a solution to that which will allow using dotnet new. Devenv.exe is Visual Studio itself and the list of commands line switches has no /New switch The \Command switch is meant to start VS and execute a command, the same way the Command Window does. There's File.NewProject opens the dialog box and doesn't accept parameters

Just curious: Why would you want to? What SDK version do you have installed?

you could use dotnet new console and change the targetframework to whatever legacy you need.

devenv does not have new command.
You can create a dotnet core template and specify dotnet framework.
dotnet new console -n MyProject --target-framework-override net48 --use-program-main

You may need to add  <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion> in csproj.
